# Help Identifying a Differential Pair-Like Symbol in a Schematic

Tags: adapter, keyboard

I am working on an adapter to connect a Xerox Docutech keyboard to a modern computer. This keyboard used a specialized, keyboard/mouse interface that does not have a modern counterpart. I have a schematic for the interface but I am uncertain about a symbol it depicts. As you can see below, the KbrdData + and - lines connect to what looks like a differential pair that generates a single, "DataFromKbrd" signal. They look a bit like op-amps... but I have no idea how those would help in this situation. What exactly are these components? How would I go about making one out of modern parts?

[image: Schematic for Keyboard Mouse Interface]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the vintage, I'd bet an Internet Doughnut that it's a 26LS32 differential receiver. http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/am26ls32ac.pdf

Comment: One symbol is diff in, se out, so that fits. But the other symbol is se in, diff out.

Comment: The other symbol is probably the companion 26LS31 differential transmitter

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising. Quick question for ya', though, does the bubble on the negative input of the supposed 26LS31 represent a simple NOT gate or should I look into something else?

Comment: There is no input on the transmitter (the 26LS31, if that's what the part is) that has a bubble.  Find the datasheet for the transmitter ... The '31 takes a TTL input and generates a differential output, with some specified slew control, and protection.  After 30 years, I don't recall the details -- use the datasheet if you need to GENERATE this signal.  The '32 takes that differential signal as an input, creating a TTL output.